Uniqueness of Gram Schmidt
Gram Schmidt turns a linearly independent list $v_1, ..., v_n$ into an orthonormal list $e_1, ..., e_n$ such that
$$span(v_1, ..., v_k) = span(e_1, ..., e_k)$$
and $\langle v_k, e_k \rangle > 0$ for $k = 1, ..., n$. Such orthonormal list is unique.
I'm attempting an inductive proof on the unique-ness part. But even the case $n = 1$ struggles me. Let $n = 1$. We have to show that there exists a unique $e$ such that $span(v) = span(e)$ with $\langle v_k, e_k \rangle > 0$.
The proof here(you should search for "6.B" in the search bar and scroll to exercise 10) seems reasonable but I think only works in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
It is obvious that there are only two vectors $u \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ in $span(v)$ such that $\Vert u \Vert = 1$. It is simply just
$$\langle \lambda v, \lambda v \rangle = 1 \Leftrightarrow \lambda^{2}\Vert v \Vert = 1 \Leftrightarrow \lambda = 1/\Vert v \Vert$$
But in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, this is
$$|\lambda|^{2} = 1/\Vert v \Vert$$
due to $\langle \lambda v, \lambda v \rangle = \lambda\overline{\lambda}v$. The fact that there are only two vectors $u$ in $span(v)$ such that $\Vert u \Vert = 1$ hold in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ is clearly not true.
In fact the whole proof the the link I've mentioned only works in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. They even conclude that
$$|\langle e_j, e_{j'} \rangle| = 1 \Rightarrow \langle e_j, e_{j'} \rangle = \pm 1$$
, which is not true in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. My question: How to correct this proof to make it work?


It’s  Gram–Schmidt

What do you mean by unique? It is a prescriptive process that has no ambiguity, and it depends on the order of the $v_k$.

I included the original question in the post. What I meant is given a specific order of v's, the list produced must be unique.

What would $\langle v_k, e_k \rangle > 0$ even mean over the complex numbers?

@MishaLavrov It means the inner product must be real and > 0

@ArturoMagidin Surely if you replace $v_i$ with $-v_i$, the condition $\langle v_i, e_i\rangle >0$ is no longer satisfied?

@MishaLavrov That's not usually part of the statement. I missed it.

Suppose the spans are equal for $k=1,...,m$ and the positive inner product condition holds (in the complex case, I am interpreting it as meaning the inner product is real and positive).
Let $u_1,...,u_m$ be the values produced by Gram Schmidt applied to $v_1,...,v_m$. We want to show that $e_k = u_k$.
You must have $e_1 = \alpha v_1$ for some $|\alpha| = {1 \over \|v_1\|}$, and since $\langle v_1, e_1 \rangle = \bar{\alpha} \|v_1\|^2 > 0$, we have $\alpha $ real and $\alpha = {1 \over \|v_1\|}$ and hence $e_1 = u_1$.
Suppose that $e_k = u_k$ for $k=1,...,n$. Then $e_{n+1} \in \operatorname{sp}\{ v_1,...,v_n, v_{n+1}\} = \operatorname{sp}\{ u_1,...,u_n, v_{n+1}\} $ and so we can write
$e_{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k u_k + \alpha v_{n+1}$, orthonormality gives $\lambda_k = - \alpha \langle u_k, v_{n+1} \rangle$ and so
$e_{n+1} = \alpha (v_{n+1} -  \sum_{k=1}^n  \langle u_k, v_{n+1} \rangle u_k) $.
Since $\|e_{n+1}\|^2 = \langle e_{n+1}, e_{n+1} \rangle = 1 = \alpha\langle e_{n+1}, v_{n+1} \rangle$, and$\langle e_{n+1}, v_{n+1} \rangle$ is real and positive, we see that $\alpha$ is real and positive. Furthermore,
$\|e_{n+1}\| = 1 = \alpha \| v_{n+1} -  \sum_{k=1}^n  \langle u_k, v_{n+1} \rangle u_k\|$, and so
$e_{n+1} = {v_{n+1} - \sum_{k=1}^n  \langle u_k, v_{n+1} \rangle u_k \over \| v_{n+1} -  \sum_{k=1}^n  \langle u_k, v_{n+1} \rangle u_k\|}$, which is the value computed by Gram Schmidt at the $n+1$st iteration. Hence $e_k = v_k$ for all $k$.

Why $\alpha$'s norm is $1$?

If $\alpha$ is real, positive and $|\alpha| = 1$ what value must it be?

You're confusing. $|\alpha| = 1$ is what you have to prove.

Take the $n=1$ case. You know that the spans of $v_1, e_1$ are the same, so they are collinear. Hence $e_1 = \alpha v_1$. Since both have unit norm, we know $|\alpha| = 1$. Since we are given that $\langle v_1, e_1 \rangle$ is real and positive, and $\langle v_1, e_1 \rangle = \alpha$, we know that $\alpha > 0$ . The only value that satisfies this is $\alpha = 1$.

$v_1$ does not have a unit norm.

Give me a minute, I will fix it.

Ok, that was more laborious than I expected.

You're using the fact that $\langle v_1, v_1\rangle = 1$ again. ALso even if that holds, $\langle v_1, e_1 \rangle = \overline{\alpha}$ instead of $\alpha$.

I am not assuming $|v_1| = 1$. Some folks, such as myself, define the inner product as linear in the second parameter. Either way the result is the same.

Why is "orthonormality gives $\lambda_k=−\alpha⟨u_k, v_n+1⟩$"

Also, $\langle e_{n+1}, e_{n + 1}\rangle=1=\alpha\langle e_{n+1},v_{n + 1}\rangle$. Why is that?

The $e_k$ are orthonormal is the answer to both. Also, remember that $e_k= u_k$ for $k=1,..., n$.

Please do clarify in your answer. Your proof looks correct.

Final question: What is your intuition on this? It's lengthy

Not much really, just that if have a linearly independent vector that is not in a span, then if you replace the vector by one orthogonal (orthonormal) to the span, there are not many choices (basically the choices are choosing some $|\alpha| = 1$).

I will provide detailed proof for the base case.
For $m = 1$, there is such a vector because $\left\langle{v_{1}, \frac{v_{1}}{\left\Vert{v_{1}}\right\Vert}}\right\rangle = \frac{1}{\left\Vert{v_{1}}\right\Vert}\left\langle{v_{1}, v_{1}}\right\rangle = \frac{{\left\Vert{v_{1}}\right\Vert}^{2}}{\left\Vert{v_{1}}\right\Vert} = \left\Vert{v_{1}}\right\Vert > 0$ and $\operatorname{span}(v_{1}) = \operatorname{span}\left(\frac{v_{1}}{\left\Vert{v_{1}}\right\Vert}\right)$. The vector $\frac{v_{1}}{\left\Vert{v_{1}}\right\Vert}$ is also the result of applying the Gram-Schmidt procedure to $v_{1}$.
Now we will show that if a normalized vector $e_{1}$ satisfies $\left\langle{v_{1}, e_{1}}\right\rangle > 0$ and $\operatorname{span}(v_{1}) = \operatorname{span}(e_{1})$ then $e_{1} = \frac{v_{1}}{\left\Vert{v_{1}}\right\Vert}$. Because $\operatorname{span}(v_{1}) = \operatorname{span}(e_{1})$ and $v_{1}, e_{1}$ are not the zero vector, there exists a scalar $a_{1}$ such that $v_{1} = a_{1}e_{1}$. Substituting to $\left\langle{v_{1}, e_{1}}\right\rangle > 0$ yields $\left\langle{a_{1}e_{1}, e_{1}}\right\rangle > 0$, which means $a_{1} > 0$. Therefore $\frac{\left\Vert{v_{1}}\right\Vert}{a_{1}} = \left\Vert\frac{v_{1}}{a_{1}}\right\Vert = \left\Vert {e_{1}}\right\Vert = 1$, which means $a_{1} = \left\Vert{v_{1}}\right\Vert$. Hence $e_{1} = \frac{v_{1}}{\left\Vert{v_{1}}\right\Vert}$.

What do you mean cumbersome? Please use English on this site. The proof is rigorous and works for both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. I edited the answer to explain why $\left\langle v_{1}, \frac{v_{1}}{\left\Vert {v_{1}} \right\Vert}\right\rangle = \left\Vert{v_{1}}\right\Vert > 0$.

Can someone explain why this answer got downvoted? As far as I understand, OP is having some trouble with the base case. I gave proof for the base case by showing that the vector obtained from the Gram-Schmidt procedure satisfies the two conditions, and every vector that satisfies the two conditions must be $v_{1} / \left\Vert {v_{1}}\right\Vert$.

The following easy-to-visualize result (and hence easy to prove)
may be taken as starting point:
LEMMA: Let $W\subset V$ be any vector subspace of dimension $n-1$. where $V$ itself is a vector subspace of some $\mathbf{R}^m$.
Its orthogonal complement in $V$ is a line and exactly two vectors in that complement are unit vectors; we can make it unique by insisting it be on the "positive side" of  $W$.
Now Gram-Schmidt has unique choice for the first vector $e_1$, simply normalize the first vector  $v_1$ in the given basis.
This $e_1$ generates a 1-dimensional $W$, and the first two vectors of original basis generate $V$, making the Lemma above applicable giving unique choice for $e_2$, in your notation.
Now we repeat the same, this time going 1 up in the dimension: $W$ will be span of $e_1,e_2$ while
$V$ is the span of $e_1, e_2, v_3$.
